# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points in fragment in android

Tags: android, google-maps

In my fragment i get error java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points  = =
i try many solution but not work

Here is my code:

```
     public void mSetUpMap() {
    /**clear the map before redraw to them*/
     googleMap.clear();
    /**Create dummy Markers List*/
    if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
        str = AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary();
    if (AppUtil.itinerary != null)
        shareUrl = AppUtil.itinerary.getShareUrl();
    Log.e("Ittt", "" + AppUtil.itinerary.getItinerary());
    ((HomeActivity) getActivity()).setTexrViewText(str);
    poiList.clear();
    poiList = AppUtil.itinerary.getPoiList();
    final List<Marker> markersList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (POI item : poiList) {
        Marker m1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new 
    LatLng(item.getLatitude(),
    item.getLongitude()))
                .title(item.getName()).anchor(0.7f, 0.6f)



   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(getCustomMarker
   ((R.drawable.m2red), 
  item.getName()))));
        markersList.add(m1);


     }

     builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker m : markersList) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
     }
     /**initialize the padding for map boundary*/
     int padding = 200;
     /**create the bounds from latlngBuilder to set into map camera*/
     LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
     /**create the camera with bounds and padding to set into map*/
     cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
     /**call the map call back to know map is loaded or not*/
     googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            /**set animated zoom camera into map*/
            googleMap.animateCamera(cu);
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            for (POI item : poiList) {
                polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(item.getLatitude(), 
            item.getLongitude()));
            }
            polylineOptions.width(5);
            polylineOptions.getPoints();

            polylineOptions.color(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
            googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
            polylineOptions.geodesic(true);



            if (!poiList.isEmpty()) {
                // Adjusting Bounds
                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                for (Marker m : markersList) {
                    builder.include(m.getPosition());
                }
                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = 
               CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 2);
                googleMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);
            }

        }
       });

        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new 
     GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
            ValueAnimator ani = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1); //change for 
       (0,1) if you want a fade in
            ani.setDuration(2000);
            ani.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() 
      {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
            ani.start();
            if (marker.getTitle().equals(poiList.get(0).getName())) {
                AppUtil.poi = poiList.get(0);
                name = poiList.get(0).getName();
                img = poiList.get(0).getImage();
                lat = poiList.get(0).getLatitude();
                lon = poiList.get(0).getLongitude();

                showPoi(name, img, lat, lon);

            } else if (marker.getTitle().equals(poiList.get(1).getName())) {
                AppUtil.poi = poiList.get(1);
                name = poiList.get(1).getName();
                img = poiList.get(1).getImage();
                lat = poiList.get(1).getLatitude();
                lon = poiList.get(1).getLongitude();

                showPoi(name, img, lat, lon);

            } else if (marker.getTitle().equals(poiList.get(2).getName())) {
                AppUtil.poi = poiList.get(2);
                name = poiList.get(2).getName();
                img = poiList.get(2).getImage();
                lat = poiList.get(2).getLatitude();
                lon = poiList.get(2).getLongitude();

                showPoi(name, img, lat, lon);


            } 
         return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I get error  LatLngBounds    bounds = builder.build(); 
this line

first time fragment work perfect but when i pressed back button and try to get this fragment i get this error

My Logcat Show:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zza(Unknown Source:8)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown 
Source:10)
at 


  info.ernica.fragment.ItinerarioFragment.mSetUpMap
 (ItinerarioFragment.java:455)
   at info.ernica.fragment.ItinerarioFragment$2.onMapReady
 (ItinerarioFragment.java:205)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source:7)
 at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown 
 Source:32)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:612)
at fg.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 
(040408-211705629):19)
at 
 com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bg.a
(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408- 
 211705629):5)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.be.run
 (:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@13280051@13.2.80 (040408- 
 211705629):5)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Post complete exception

Comment: please see edited question @Redman

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47102127/java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-included-points?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking whether poiList is empty, you need to check if markersList is empty in the `setOnMapLoadedCallback` method.

```
if (!markersList.isEmpty()) {
    // Adjusting Bounds
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    for (Marker m : markersList) {
        builder.include(m.getPosition());
    }
    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
    CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = 
    CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 2);
    googleMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);
}
```

From the error it looks like your `markersList` is empty. It needs to contain at least one point for `LatLngBounds.Builder` to work properly.